# Revert Column and Row Yii TbExtendedGridView

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii, cgridview

I'm displaying a simple table containing two headers 'variable' and 'value',
The display would look like:

```
Variable| Value
entry1| value1
entry2| value2
```

How do revert the columns and rows to make it look like

```
Variable  | entry1 | entry2
Value     | value1 | value2
```

My current code:

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbExtendedGridView', array(
    'sortableRows'=>true,
    'afterSortableUpdate' => 'js:function(id, position){ console.log("id: "+id+", position:"+position);}',
    'type'=>'striped bordered',
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => array(                
        array( 
           'header'=>'Variable',
           'name'=>'variable_id',
           'value'=>'$data->variable->name',
           'filter'=>CHtml::listData(Study::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'variable_name'),
           ),
        'value',
        ),
    ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the documentation, there isn't one way to change from row to columns or vice and versa.

[YiiBooster Reference](http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/components.html#tables)

[Class reference of CGridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView)

So, what you should do is, create a GridView without header or use the public property of CGridView **[hideHeader](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView#hideHeader-detail)** that allow you to hide the headers, anyway, you have to change the data to display with 3 columns instead of 2.

Change from:

```
$data[0][0] = 'entry1';
$data[0][1] = 'value1';
$data[1][0] = 'entry2';
$data[1][1] = 'value2';
$gridDataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider($data);

// $gridColumns with header
$gridColumns = array(
    array('name'=>'variable', 'header'=>'Variable'),
    array('name'=>'value', 'header'=>'Value'),
);

$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$gridDataProvider,
    'template'=>"{items}",
    'columns'=>$gridColumns,
));
```

To:

```
$data[0][0] = 'Variable';
$data[0][1] = 'entry1';
$data[0][2] = 'value1';
$data[1][0] = 'Value';
$data[1][1] = 'entry2';
$data[1][2] = 'value2';
$gridDataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider($data);

$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$gridDataProvider
));
```